# Redis: Spring Boot application requests keep failing while shutdown one of the redis master node

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, caching, redis

Blocked by a redis issue these days, thanks for any suggestion in advance. Below are some details:

> Evn: Spring boot 2.0.3.RELEASE, Redis 3.0.6 cluster(3 master, 3 slave),
>
> Starter: spring-boot-starter-data-redis(defaul version with spring boot), which means the application will use letture as the redis client

---

Error scenaro:

1. Start the application and send some requests, everything goes fine
2. Stop on the master node, the corresponding slave will takes about 20s to failover to be a master, which also goes fine.
3. During the upper 20s(failover time) period, if keep sending the reuqest.

   - In the 20s, requests fail, this is expected
   - After the 20s(the slave becomes a master), requests still fail, this is **unexpected**
4. During the upper 20s(failover time) period, if no reuqest sent. After the slave becomes a master, the laster requests goes fine.

> no write operation during upper steps

---

config:

`conf
    cache:
      type: redis
    redis:
      cluster: ip1:port(m),ip1:port(s),ip2:port(m),ip2:port(s),ip3:port(m),ip3:port(s)
      max-redirects: 3
    password: xxxx
    timeout: 1000
    pool:
      max-active: 500
      max-wait: 1500`

---

Code: just create a simple `CacheManager` bean

`java
@Bean
public CacheManager cacheManager(RedisConnectionFacotry redisConnectionFacotry){
   return new RedisCacheManager(RedisCacheWriter.nonLockingRedisCacheWriter(redisConnectionFacotry), 
          redisCacheConfig)   // set serializer and timeout
}`

we use spring cache in the code with annotations like: `@CachePut` etc. The total data in redis is less than 10M and total volumn of redis is 2G.

NEEDS YOUR HELP :)

Comment: change to jedis, issue gone.

Answer (score 1):

Issue goes as we change from lettuce to jedis, with no root cause found.